# Count times X appears in JSON

Tags: php, json

So, I have the following code:

```
{
    "request": {
        "data_start": "2013-01-01",
        "data_end": "2014-06-13"
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 1,
        "httpStatus": 200,
        "data": {
            "data": [{
                "Stat": {
                    "offer_id": "8",
                    "clicks": "0",
                    "date": "2013-01-14",
                    "month": "01",
                    "year": "2013",
                    "affiliate_id": "1000"
                }
            }, {
                "Stat": {
                    "offer_id": "8",
                    "clicks": "26",
                    "date": "2013-02-06",
                    "month": "02",
                    "year": "2013",
                    "affiliate_id": "1000"
                }
            }, {
                "Stat": {
                    "offer_id": "8",
                    "clicks": "12",
                    "date": "2013-02-06",
                    "month": "02",
                    "year": "2013",
                    "affiliate_id": "2"
                }
            }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

I need to know how many times "date": "2013-02-06" for example appears in this JSON, using PHP. Is this possible? Just to be clear, this is only an example, the actual JSON is several thousand lines long.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have it as a PHP object or string?

Comment: Also, your JSON object seems to be bad. Check jslint.com to first correct your JSON and edit the question to repost the valid JSON

Comment: Have you tried `json_decode()` on the string and then iterating through the data array?

Comment: @MikeBrant BrettFromLA has the easiest solution. That's why I asked for more clarifications. If you have it as PHP string, use Brett's solution. On the contrary, if you have it as PHP Object. Convert it to string using json_encode() and use Brett's solution.

Comment: @PrashantBalan That really depends.  Certailny you can count the teh number of occurences in the string using `substr_count` (which would be better than the solution proposed). But at the end of the day, is this question really about learning how to work with data structures encoded in JSON? For example, what if the date you are looking for in the string also shows up in the `request` element?  You would count 1 extra occurence. Without getting into more complex regex solutions you have no way to accommodate that.  Dealing with the data as an appropriate data structure solves that.

Comment: @MikeBrant Question was how many times it appears in the JSON. Not specified which node.

Comment: @PrashantBalan Sure that is the question, though my guess is since the OP is just learning, he didn't frame the question properly.

Comment: @MikeBrant if you would agree, solution cannot be based on assumptions.

Comment: @PrashantBalan Sure. I am simply proposing that the OP consider using the data passed along to the script as data rather than a string.  If someone passed you a PHP serialized string, would you not typically just deserialize and work with the data instead of the string?  What happens when he need to do something else, like display the items in the data that have this matching date? More string manipulation? As a person that is clearly learning PHP (and maybe programming as a whole) we should point out that this is more than just a string, but rather a data serilaize.

Comment: @PrashantBalan You noted that BrettFromLA's solution is the "easiest".  I would argue that it is not.  To me the easiest thing is to deserialize the data and work with it. All the string-based solutions being presented here are fragile and likely to break if there are some minor changes in the JSON being passed in. If you work with the actual data structures, you only need to concern yourself with changing the code if the data structure itself changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way as Mike pointed out below is to use substr_count(). This is implemented in C as a native method in PHP. This method will not consider overlapping patterns (see the PHP documentation for an example).

If the needle is exactly the same each time and contains an overlap, you can loop and use strpos, moving the offset each time.

```
$offset = 0;
$count = 0;
while(($offset = strpos($json, '"date": "2013-02-06"', $offset) !== false) {
  $offset++;
  $count++;
}
```

The other option if the needle is not exact in each case (extra spaces, etc):

```
$count = preg_match_all('"[dD]ate":\w+"2013-02-06"', $json);
```

RegEx is slower so only use as needed.

If the data needs to be used much more intensively, the best thing is to deserialize it and go from there. Deserializing is going to lead to a > 2x memory utilization and incur the cycles required to deserialize. It's important to consider the trade offs of each approach.

Comment: If one is insiting on using a string manipulation approach, why not just `$count = substr_count($json, $date_search_string)`?

Comment: Because I honestly forgot it was there. Definitely a better solution for this case, but substr_count won't consider overlapping instances. The method above would (Just adding this as a warning for future readers).

Answer (score 0):

As @PrashantBalan brought up, if it's a string you can probably do a count really simply. One way is to split the string into an array, using "date": "2013-02-06" as the delimiter, then just return the number of elements in the array (minus one).

Comment: @PrashantBalan I bet your answer would have been a lot more elegant and descriptive than my pseudocode!

Comment: Splitting to an array is probably the last thing you want to do from a memory perspective. Right idea though. I'd loop using strpos and keep uping the offset.

Comment: @ErikNedwidek Good point! You should add your comment as an Answer. You'll get some upvotes and points that way.

Comment: @BrettFromLA good point. I'll do that even though I'm not generally here for the glory. ;)

Comment: This is actual problematic.  What if the date you are trying to count in the `data` element is also present in the `request` element?  You end up over-counting.  You should deserialize this string and work with the data structure that is represented.

Comment: Also if you were to use string approach, just use `substr_count()`

Answer (score 0):

Simply deserialize the JSON and filter the data array inside of it on your search date.

```
$json = '...'; // your JSON string
$obj = json_decode($json);
$data_array = $obj->response->data->data;
$search_date = '2013-02-06'; // whatever your search date is

// filter the data array down to those items matching the date
$filtered_data = array_filter($data_array, function($item) use ($search_date) {
    return $item->Stat->date = $search_date;
}
// get count of filtered items
$filtered_count = count($filtered_data);
```